# Minimal OS that boots into RDP login prompt?

Tags: remote-desktop, remote-access, rdp, thin-client

I'm doing some research into thin clients. I've configured [an RDP server](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remote_Desktop_Protocol) on a home PC with Linux. I have an older desktop computer that I want to use as a thin client.

Although I could just install an RDP client on its current OS (Windows XP), I'm looking for a minimalistic OS that presents the user with an RDP login prompt. This should greatly decrease the computer's startup time. Is there such an OS out there?

Comment: would you consider something like OpenBSD, it'll take a bit to configure, but I'd say it's extremely light weight. (both size and speed wise)

Comment: What RDP server software did you use?

Comment: @Kev: xrdp at http://xrdp.sourceforge.net/.

Comment: @Earlz: so you don't think that there are any out-of-the-box solutions? I just need a login screen for RDP where I can enter the host's IP address, the username and the password.

Comment: No, I don't believe there is an out of the box solution. I believe it'll require at least some configuration no matter what.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may be interested in [Thinstation](http://www.thinstation.org/), which I believe should fit your needs admirably.

Comment: There seems to be a lot of configuring involved... http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/thinstation/index.php?title=FAQ I'd rather have an ISO that's ready to be written to a CD or USB pendrive, but if this is the only decent option I'll take it.

Comment: @Peiter, yes there is some configuring to do but you only do that once. You then create an image that can be used on as many machines as you want.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, one of them can be found on thin client PCs: Windows CE.

I'm sure there's *nix distros out there that can do a more exciting job :-)